# Python tool to pre-check inadvertent omission of keyword arguments

Tags: python

I found no tool that detects traps/pitfalls/gotchas of python regarding inadvertent omission of keywords in standard function calls

Consider:

```
{
re.search(‘test’, ‘TeSt’, re.IGNORECASE)
re.match(‘test’, ‘TeSt’, re.IGNORECASE)
re.sub(‘test’, ‘xxxx’, ‘Testing’, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
}
```

Without flags= re.IGNORECASE is in count!!

I suffered a lot of this “gotcha”

Any ideas on how omission of keywords can be pre-checked

Comment: It is not possible to prevent the situation you are describing. You are asking for a tool that detects when you are passing the 'wrong' integer as positional argument 3 to a function that takes 3 or more positional arguments, the third of which is an integer.

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried Pyflakes, Pylint no luck.
PyCharm Community intellisense/autocompletion no help.

**Design of re.sub itself is defective** my opinion.
_flags should have preceded count with no keyword_.

Comment: You could compile your regexps before using them, which makes individual calls a bit simpler.